# number of seconds since start of week?

Tags: c++, date

I've been trying out Howard's date library. There are many examples for getting the number of seconds since midnight of a certain day, but not since the start of week to which the day belongs. Following  the examples I produced this code:

```
using timepoint_t = std::chrono::time_point<
  std::chrono::system_clock,
  std::chrono::nanoseconds
>;

timepoint_t tp; // input
auto dp = std::chrono::floor<date::weeks>(tp); // output, should point to start of week?
```

But the results are wrong. For example, tp:

```
2018-10-25T11:26:00.397836134Z
```

will produce dp:

```
2018-10-25T00:00:00.000000000Z
```

which is midnight of the 25th, not midnight of the 21th. What is the most direct way to produce the correct output?

Comment: You would increase chances of a good answer if you convert your example to [mcve] - so people can just use your code as it is, compile and play with it.

Comment: @Slava it would be really long-winded, since you have string conversions in play :( Anyway, I know the correct answer, it just bothers me, that it is so complicated. Why not just the cast?

Comment: If you have a conversion *from* a string, then skip that in your MCVE and hard-code a time-point. Converting *to* a string is easy using [`to_time_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/system_clock/to_time_t) and [`put_time`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/put_time). [This `time_point` reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/time_point) have a very good example on how to print a time-point. Other than that, don't forget that the "M" in MCVE stands for *Minimal*, create a program which have the problem you ask about, but nothing more.

Comment: Thank you for next time, the date library seems very convoluted to me, so I didn't know about that feature.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've upvoted user1095108's self answer as it gets the correct answer.  But I wanted to add more information that wouldn't all fit in a comment.

The "start of the week" is not universally agreed upon.  Some countries obverse Monday as the start of the week, as does the ISO standard.  And other countries observe Sunday as the start of the week.  This library tries to stay as neutral as possible on this issue.

Even once you nail down which weekday you're aiming for, you also need to nail down where on the planet you want to consider when finding the second the week starts.

Judging from your code, I'm going to assume:

1. The week starts on Sunday.
2. We want to find the start of the week according to UTC.

For the following code, assume:

```
using namespace date;
using namespace std::chrono;
```

just to keep things from getting overly verbose.

The first thing I would do is transform the input into a `time_point` with a precision of seconds:

```
auto tp = floor<seconds>(system_clock::now());
```

Then, in order to do weekday computations, such as finding the weekday of the input `tp`, one is going to need another `time_point` with a precision of days:

```
auto dp = floor<days>(tp);
```

You can construct a `weekday` directly from a day-precision `time_point` (`dp`), instead of going through the more expensive computation of forming a `year_month_weekday`:

```
weekday{dp}
```

then (as you show) subtract off the number of days since the start of the week:

```
dp -= weekday{dp} - Sunday;
```

Now you have two `time_point`s:  Your input, and the start of the week.  You can simply subtract them to get the number of seconds into the week:

```
std::cout << tp - dp << '\n';
```

Now the reason that `floor<weeks>(tp)` doesn't give you the desired result is that `system_clock` is [Unix Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time).  This measure counts time since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC (neglecting leap seconds).  And 1970-01-01 was a Thursday.  So truncating a `system_clock::time_point` to a precision of `weeks` defines the "start of the week" as Thursday.

For even more fun, compute the number of seconds since the start of the week in a local time, which may involve daylight savings adjustments.  In this case the computation has more than one right answer:  Do you count physical seconds, which makes some weeks not have exactly 604800s, or do you count "calendrical seconds"?  For example is Nov/4/2018 1:00 EST (America/New_York) 1 or 2 hours into the week?  Once you decide which is the right answer, this library can compute it.

Comment: Howard, you need to fix your answer, since you changed the default start of week to Monday.

Comment: This date lib has no "default start of the week". I _did_ make it easier to do conversions between integral types and `weekday` types using either the C system `[0, 6] <-> [Sun, Sat]`, or the ISO system `[1, 7] <-> [Mon, Sun]`. But `weekday` difference is always unsigned mod 7 in this library. That is, you can subtract any two `weekday`s and you will always get an answer in the range [0, 6]. If you add that number of days back you always get the original. The algebra just works: `a - b = c` implies `a = b + c`. This library treats `weekday`s as a circular range, with no beginning or end.

Comment: Still, you need to know, that, as it is, Sunday comes after Monday, i.e. Sunday - Monday = 6 and subtracting six days from a Monday would yield Tuesday in the previous week AFAIK.

Comment: It is true that `Sunday - Monday == days{6}`.  And it is true that `Monday - days{6} == Tuesday`.  But it is also true that `Monday - Sunday == days{1}`.  The code above works, no matter what day you decide is the first day of the week (as long as you have the expression: `dp -= weekday{dp} - my_first_day_of_week;`).

Comment: The `weekday` difference algorithm is more complex than just converting the each `weekday` to the underlying integral type and subtracting those integrals.  https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date/blob/master/include/date/date.h#L1817-L1825  Fuller explanation: http://howardhinnant.github.io/date_algorithms.html#weekday_difference

Comment: Be sure to remind the c++ standard committee of your changes :) For all I know, they are tracking an old version of your library (i.e. Sunday == 0).

Comment: Here's the C++20 `weekday` spec: http://eel.is/c++draft/time.cal.wd .  Currently, both in my library, and in the spec:  `weekday{0} == Sunday`, `weekday{7} == Sunday`, `Sunday.c_encoding() == 0` and `Sunday.iso_encoding() == 7`.

Answer (score 4):

Most of Howard's calendar calculations seem to be based off of `date:days`. So you're out of luck with `date::weeks`, it seems. One possible answer is:

```
auto dp(std::chrono::floor<date::days>(tp));
dp -= date::year_month_weekday(dp).weekday() - date::Sunday;
```

The number of seconds is then obtained as the customary  `std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(tp - dp).count()`. Could it be the lack of support for `date::weeks` in `std::chrono`, that the `date::weeks` cast does not work? Howard's `date::floor()` gives the same output as `std::chrono::floor()` though.